# How can I move files by USB between a version 6.1 iPod Touch and a Linux machine?

Tags: usb, unix, ipod-touch, file-transfer, airplane-mode

I've recently dug out my old 5th Gen (A1421) model iPod Touch and put it back to factory settings. It's currently running version 6.1 (10B141) of its OS. I don't want to find that a software update has broken it one day, so my goal is to keep it offline as much as possible (specifically, Airplane Mode) and have it only talk to my PC, a Xubuntu 20.04 Linux machine. In line with this goal, I've never linked it up with any sort of iTunes software or Apple account.

It was my hope that with the iPod set up as above, I would be able to connect it by USB to my PC and transfer files as I pleased. My goal is to use it to play mp3s. After all, Linux typically ignores whatever file system visibility restrictions that the connected device is trying to enforce. Now that I've tried that, my PC is only reporting that two devices exist: "iPod", contained only an empty DCIM folder, and "Documentes on iPod touch", containing nothing. When I try to move files to either of these, I either get an error message saying that a file doesn't exist or an error message saying that a directory doesn't exist. Unlocking the iPod does not change this, and the iPod does not seem to respond at all to anything that I'm doing on the PC, other than trying to charge its battery from my machine.

So, given my goals, what can I do to be able to move files between the two devices? Could anything that I've done, such as putting the iPod in Airplane Mode, be to blame for my difficulties? [I have managed to use ifuse to get new files on to the iPod](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398912/385841), but the iPod itself shows no signs of recognizing them.

Comment: "...and transfer files as I please." If you are looking for a glorified USB thumb drive then you already have it. Drop those files in either of these folders. Otherwise tell us what you are trying to do; add music, pictures, videos... what exactly?

Comment: @SteveChambers It's not working as a thumb drive. Reread the last two sentences of the second paragraph. However, my goal is to use it to play mp3s.

Comment: Sorry, ADD moment ;-). But you might best ask this on Linux discussions. Yes there are Linux guys here, but our primary expertise is with macOS. And you can easily turn off automatic updates in Software Update. And it has been a while but I think that the file system on your iPod is HFS+ so that *might* be a problem.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @SteveChambers [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398912/385841) might be more suited to your expertise.

Comment: I just restored an old 4th Gen iPod Classic...Even in Windows 7 it doesn’t show up as a Thumbdrive (they used to).  For it to do that now,  you have to put it in USB drive mode which I believe needs to be done through iTunes.  Either way, you’ll need iTunes so it might not be a bad idea to just set up a VM on your Linux box with Windows and iTunes so you can manage your Music.  I’m casually working on a project to restore a Zune (yeah, a Zune) and have a VM with Win7 and Zune software - it’s not that big a resource hog.

Comment: @Allan Ending up having to take your advice and just stick iTunes on a VM. It worked. If you want an accepted answer, just submit something like your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR — Try GtkPod. If no luck, install the latest version of `libimobiledevice` and try Rhythmbox. You may need to bootstrap the process using iTunes. You may be completely out of luck with a 5th-generation iPod Touch.**

iPods and iOS devices use a proprietary database-style design, with seemingly arbitrarily named files scattered around the filesystem; not a simple artist/album/track hierarchy of audio files like you probably have on your computer. You will not be able to achieve what you want just by using a file explorer. What you're looking for is a drop-in replacement for iTunes, software which understands how the iPod handles music files. Back in the the day, YamiPod was a very good option (I personally used it on Windows Me, since iTunes only supported XP onwards), and GtkPod is still a popular choice for Linux users of older devices, but both now appear to be unmaintained.

Most music library managers and players for Linux, such as Rhythmbox, have implemented iPod syncing (music only), so I'd try using that, but YMMV. For a larger list of such software, see [Comparison of iPod file managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_iPod_file_managers) on Wikipedia (though do note that some of the info there about what supports what seems to be outdated).

Under the hood, most apps that support interacting with iPods and iOS devices, including Rhythmbox, use [`libimobiledevice`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice), which is an impressively feature-rich API. Unfortunately, there is a clear lack of user-friendly software that takes full advantage of it (beyond music syncing). The library is probably available in your distro's repos, but they may not have the latest version; ensure you have the latest version installed if syncing in Rhythmbox doesn't appear to be working. It doesn't have support for the latest devices/iOS versions (indeed, their FAQ emphasises the lack of full support, but doesn't go into detail about what specifically is and isn't supported), but I believe there is good support at least up to iOS 6.1.2, so it's worth a shot.

If none of that works, or if you want to explore additional functionality, take a look at the [Debian article on the subject](https://wiki.debian.org/iPhone).

Comment: I've tried Rhythmbox before. It doesn't even recognise that the iPod exists.

Comment: @J.Mini What version of `libimobiledevice` is installed?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Version 1.2.1 is in the Focal Universe repo as `libimobiledevice-utils`, so give that a try before bothering to compile the latest version. I can't imagine having 1.3.0 installed instead will matter for a 5th-gen iPod touch.

Comment: Fascinating, I've apparently had ```libimobiledevice-utils``` installed all along. Whatever Rhythmbox was trying to do, it mustn't have picked up on that. I'll report back after trying GtkPod.

Comment: GtkPod does not appear to support 5th-generation iPod Touches, but does at least seem to recognise that I've tried to connect an iPod, the Debian article appears to violate my requirement of avoiding iTunes, and the Wikipedia stuff seems far too out of date. It's a shame. If my iPod was one generation older, this answer would've been perfect.

Comment: I actually have a 4th-gen iPod touch on iOS 6.1.6 sitting beside me, so I might test it with Rhythmbox on Xubuntu just to see if it really works.

Comment: Never did get around to trying it, sadly, ended up forgetting about this. I don't currently have the iPod to hand — maybe in a couple of weeks when I can probably get a hold of it again, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Well, a year to the date later, I finally got around to backing up and resetting my iPod to try this out on Ubuntu 20.04. The device shows up as "iPod" (in which camera files can be seen) and "Documents on iPod", and the `ideviceinfo` command from `libimobiledevice-utils` outputs info, but no luck with any syncing software (tried Gtkpod, Rhythmbox, Clementine, no device shows up). If I get some more time, I'll see if it works when jailbroken and/or if I downgrade the device to iOS 6.1.2, which some sources suggest make it possible.

Comment: Best of luck. I ended up using a virtual machine.