# How can an iPod touch play mp3 transferred as files on storage instead of Apple sync using iTunes?

Tags: usb, software-recommendation, ipod-touch, file-transfer, mp3

I am currently looking for ways to transfer files [from my Linux machine to my version 6.1 iPod Touch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398905/385841). Following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IOS#The_iFuse_Way), I have been able to use the ifuse package to treat my iPod Touch like a USB stick and put the mp3s that I want on it. However, after dismounting the iPod, I can't find anything on it that acknowledges the existence of the new files. So, I have the following questions:

I don’t know which (if any) folders of my iPod Touch process files or make them available to any music player app.

Note: The iPod Touch is on version 6.1 (10B141) of its OS and is a 5th Gen (A1421) model. It may be assumed that it has been reset to factory settings and has never seen iTunes or an Apple account, and never will.

Are there apps or folders to which a native app will play these mp3 once they are copied via USB to a Linux machine?

Comment: Hopefully my edit clarifies the overall goal. I’ve added the software recommendation tag instead of unix since that more accurately scopes the issue of the native app not looking for sound files not already cataloged in a sandboxed app storage-based  database.

Answer (score 1):

The native app for music playing on the iPod touch assumes music files are stored in a database that indexes their local storage in a sandboxed manner. Since it was designed to only receive songs by syncing with itunes software directly from Mac or Windows supported OS, it’s not clear there is a general folder that gets indexed or processed for playing like some other apps that expect to be thrown a folder of files to play.

For Linux, you should use an [alternative software "rhythmbox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox) to accomplish this import to the database of playable files.

If you use ifuse, it will only transfer the songs like an usb drive for storage only and not for playing. This mirrors the storage function of the original iPods where you could dump files, but they’re not indexed or processed for apps to use. The files app for iOS came after your version of iOS so this function to store and play arbitrary files came later than iOS 6 and isn’t available to you. Perhaps others know a player app that might be able to play these or jailbreak your device to add this function.

Comment: I've tried Rhythumbox before. For this specific generation of iPod, it will not work. It will recognise that an iPod has been connected, but it can't do anything with it.